# How to Mock the ActivityContext Class

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

I wanted to mock the System.Activities.NativeActivityContext & System.Activities.ActivityContext for my unit test.

i.e.

```
using Moq;
using Autofac.Extras.Moq;

var executionContext = new Mock<NativeActivityContext>();
```

Since this class does not have zero parameter constructor, I'm unable to mock, neither not able to create object for this.

[image: This is the definition of NativeActivityClass which does not have constructor defined]

Note: Looks Like there is no constructor defined in this class

Can anyone help me how to mock or create object of this classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Moq of a concrete class with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214531/create-a-moq-of-a-concrete-class-with-dependencies)

Comment: There is no constructor in the NativeActivityContext class. Then what kind of dependecies I can pass?

Comment: if there is no constructor , it means it uses default parameter-less constructor. You've said, *"Since this class does not have zero parameter constructor"* - (I assumed it has parameterized constructor) if it is not defined and no other constructor defined, it has a default constructor.

Comment: Hi, Since this class is part of .Net Class Library, I do not know much about it. But You are right, it should allow me to create a default constructor. but when i use var context = new NativeActivityContext(); getting error "NativeActivityContext does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments". I'm confused

Comment: It is possible that this class is simply hides initialization from you. It `internal` constructor or even private. You can reflect it and look inside